# Bundle difference in onCreate (Activity) and onCreateActivity (Fragment)

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am still new to Android programming, i did search for checking the difference between Bundle in Activity and in Fragment and what are the use cases of these.

Please give me the difference with exact use case.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a different bundle.
When you create activity you get system or custom bundle (with save data).
When you create fragment you can put same date from activity (ex same id) but this will be a new bundle.
If you want same data in frament like `super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);` in activity, you need to return this bundle to activity, and for restoring you must parse this data in activity and put to fragment.